# Is it possible to sort files in directories depending on their file name?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it's possible to use python to sort a database of pictures depending on their filename. I've seen that it's possible but with their extension or their entire name but not a certain part of the filename.

For exemple : `W_X_Y_Z.extension` is my file

I would like to only use the part `"X"` of the file name to create a directory and put the file in but I can't find anything...

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English, I'm French !

Comment: Try: `'W_X_Y_Z.extension'.split('_')[1]`.

Comment: Will you be sorting on the whole filename ? or just a part like "X" ? And when you say *"use the part "X" of the file name to create a directory"*, is X the same for every file ? Or are going to put in each file in its own directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the specific region of the characters, based on which you want to sort

```
import os

file_list = os.listdir("~/home")

def xchars(x):
    return(x[2:3])

sorted(file_list, key = xchars)
```